# Why are these inequalities contradictory? How would I go about proving that algebraically?

Tags: inequality

You don't need to understand the specifics of this explanation or the context, just the inequalities:

[image]

I don't understand how we can prove that there's a contradiction. If $w_{0} > -w_{1}$ and $w_{0} > -w_{2}$, then what can we conclude about $-w_{1} -w_{2}$? All I can come up with is that $2w_{0} > -w_{1} - w_{2}$, and that tells me nothing.

Comment: Perhaps more information is available regarding the $\omega_i$ but if there isn't then your reasoning is correct.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure where the $w_{0}$ came from or why they used inequalities in their explanation, but it makes more sense in my mind to show that if $0(w_{1}) + 1(w_{2}) = 1$, then $w_{2} = 1$, and if $1(w_{1}) + 0(w_{2}) = 1$, then $w_{1} = 1$. But then $1(w_{1}) + 1(w_{2}) = 2$, which is not $0$.

Comment: My guess is that the context for the problem provides more information, but of course there are lots of typos in math books.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $w_0\le -w_1-w_2<2w_0$ with $w_0\le 0$. This is impossible.

Comment: I don't get it :(

Comment: You have that $w_0$ is negative, hence $2w_0 \leq w_0$

Comment: Ah, I got it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, $w_0\leq 0$ and $-w_1,-w_2<w_0$ so $-w_1,-w_2$ are each negative numbers and the sum of negative numbers is less than each of the numbers being added (Think like $-3+-4=-7$, $-7<-3,-4$), so

$$-w_1-w_2<-w_1,-w_2<w_0$$

which says $w_0>-w_1-w_2$ which contradicts $w_0\leq -w_1-w_2$.